# CSS - How make text up another text and button in the down

Tags: css

[image]

Hello! How make the text 'RUB' which display in image? And how make button in the down of div block?

Comment: Where's your code that you tried?

Comment: Please post the page you got this example from and anything you've already tried

Answer (score -1):

I've changed it:
[image]

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;width: 152px;">
    <div style="float: left; width:120px; padding-top:20px;">
        <span style="font-size: 42px;">6450.</span>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:30px;">
        <div><img src="" alt="RUB"></div>
        <div><span style="font-size: 24px;">00</span></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div style="width:154px;clear: both;display: block; text-align: center;background-color: green;border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;">
        Buy
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I have misunderstood. You should describe it clearly.

Comment: <div style="float: left;">
  <span style="font-size: 42px;">6450.</span>
  </div>
  <div >
   <div><img src=""></div>
   <div><span style="font-size: 12px;">00</span></div>
  </div>